# Import a list of users from flat file to AD group

Tags: powershell, active-directory, bulk-load, active-directory-group

I have two questions really, both surrounding the same topic.

I need to be able to create a flat file and use this file to import the users listed in the file to a specific group in Active Directory.  They will already exist in AD, just not be in the group.

Secondarily to that, I also need to be able to use similar methodologies to remove users from the AD group using a different flat file.

Can this be done?  The list of users will be in the 100s so I really don't want to have to do it by hand....

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible with Powershell: [Managing Active Directory with Windows PowerShell](http://www.powershellpro.com/powershell-tutorial-introduction/powershell-tutorial-active-directory/) This is for Powershell 1.0, there are a lot of tutorials for the same task with Powershell 2, which is a lot easier.